# choosing tense in the If-clause of a mixed conditional

Tags: conditionals

Suppose A, B and C plan to meet at a place. A and B reach the place in time. C calls one of them to say that he'll be late, because he left just five minutes ago.

A to B:

1. A: If he **had left** at least half an hour ago, he **would** **be** here now!

Q: I know the above sentence is called a **mixed conditional**. But do native speakers use simple past tense instead of past perfect in the If-clause of such a conditional sentence where the context makes it clear that the If-clause is talking about a **past counterfactual** situation? Like this:

2. If he **left** at least half an hour ago, he **would be** here now! (still implying that C **did not** leave at the said time)

**Note**: Sentence (2) is **not** a *second conditional*.

Comment: You really wanna know what native speakers do? Be careful what you ask for. It's not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

*If he had left half an hour ago ...*

This means that I know for a fact that he did **not** leave half-an-hour ago. In other words it translates to:

*If he had decided to leave half an hour ago (but he didn't) ... then he would be here.*

---

*If he left half an hour ago ...*

This means that I allow the fact that he may have left half-an-hour ago.

*If it is true that he left half an hour ago ... then he should be here. (maybe we just haven't met up with him yet)*

Comment: *If it is true that he left half an hour ago...*----But the context says otherwise. A and B **both know** for a fact that C left only **five minutes** ago.

Comment: @Mr. X - Correct and therefore you cannot use sentence 2 in this context.